# How to control recent appended element by clicking on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create c_box_id div block by using an append function.

```
var c_box =  '<div id="c_box_id">...</div>';
$("#p_div").append(c_box);
```

I have an anchor tag to trigger a function to remove this box.

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "remove_c_box(c_box_id)">Remove</a>

function remove_c_box(name) {
    name = "#" + name;
    $(name).remove() // This doesn't work because c_box_id is a dynamic element
}
```

I can't use the event delegation below to remove c_box_id because it is not clicked.

```
 $('body').on('click', '#c_box_id', function(){
     //...
 });
```

How can I remove the c_box block by clicking on the anchor tag above?

*** c_box_id is not a fixed string. It is generated randomly for a set of an anchor tag and a div block.

For example:

```
<div class="ajxiu2"> </div>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "remove_c_box('ajxiu2')">Remove</a>

<div class="sd5iu2"> </div>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "remove_c_box('sd5iu2')">Remove</a>

<div class="cxj2c3"> </div>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "remove_c_box('cxj2c3')">Remove</a>

<div class="i5xxas"> </div>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "remove_c_box('i5xxas')">Remove</a>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `// This doesn't work because c_box_id is a dynamic element` - Not true, that should work. Do you have more than one element with the id `c_box_id`?

Comment: yes. I have more than 1. Also the c_box_id is not fixed. It is created randomly and unpredicatble.

Comment: did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: *"I have more than 1"* apart from id's needing to be unique I doubt you want all removed in which case not enough html structure  is shown and expected behavior not explained properly. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JasonP Typo. No, I can't use a class because each of c_box_id must be unique, when I click on an anchor tag with an id, its gonna remove the c_box_id with that id.

Comment: @LouisTran but the `<a>` shown has no ID. You need to spend more time providing proper details. You oversimplified your example

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. There was no error in the console. I just can't select the appended c_box_id to remove it.

Comment: I see what he's saying with the ids-- each c_box_id will be replaced with a randomized string of some sort, so they will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `#` prefix to id for a jQuery ID selector

```
function remove_c_box(id) {
    $('#' + id).remove() ;
}
```

And make sure to quote id string in `onclick`

```
 onclick = "remove_c_box('ajxiu2')"
```